# Where are the Firebase Access Denied messages logged on the server?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Where are the Firebase database rules "Access Denied" messages logged on the Firebase server?

We  are using the JavaScript web version of Firebase client libraries.  The answer below is referring to Android or iOS but can we get automatic logging / analytics on the Web version?

For example, one of our customers sees:

> firebase issue Error: permission_denied at
>   /companydata/Global/eJztlD9PwzAQxb8K8pyBVqJDtkIpCtA/IpQFMRzJtbXq2NHlUhRV/e6ck4LKQioQagc23z3n+efn2Bs1JUx1AoyFCp83KmLM7rBSoZq7OVZWBWryWiCtgbWzjSK9JzAlynDs/IQcCdiRCs8DFRUTGczBFBioK2cZtEWK0lqcAqHlz64KbWmM/+beLQTC7Ck7h2hhHWGMQMlyqNGID1OJ22AfNVtQG+jsMj4F0hbKv0L0IAcSyrHrHx97s04r6Okn8vtfEmiF3JbjLeRg/6P8Pkqu8k5bkCNnsTobrfjLJjvHueSpy5ZtwP2yYAKj4UjAL4GKHbFw+XdfqhtyZb4rD01/oAkT3xFy7/jg3obaMNLOc5J7UQqVlBTO4oH67HXrZSxk2KiirD+eaplX8zEQ97ne+COsROpeSATk0jJhH0ivF6hry5qrceMzNXKbtu/y+E4I:
>   Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.(…)

I'd like to see these errors in a log somewhere on the Firebase console.

Is there a place to see data rules denials?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no server-side location where these error messages are captured that you have access to.

You will have to reproduce the client's behavior locally or use the Firebase Database rules simulator to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to do it (logging denied access), manually.
`Firebase analytics` collects some events by default. [Here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en) you can find the list of those events. And [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log) is an example of how to add log events in android.

Comment: Thanks I've updated the question.  We  are using the javascript web version of firebase client libraries.